# what are compiled simulators and Instruction Set Interpreter based Simulators?

Tags: simulator

What are compiled simulators and Instruction Set Interpreter based Simulators? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled simulators simply compile the code with the host machine's compilers and run it natively on the host. Instruction set interpreters simulate the code running on the actual machine, and the code is exactly the same as the real code -- compiled with the same compilers.

The iOS simulators are compiled simulators -- they simply compile the code with an x86 compiler instead of an ARM compiler. Thus it doesn't simulate everything, e.g., NEON instructions.